# Google Apis Failed to launch browser for authorization. See inner exception for details

Tags: android, debugging, exception, google-sheets-api, build-error

I am trying to build an Android application which implements the Google Sheets api; however, when I attempt to create the user credentials, I get an error stating that the browser failed to launch. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
async Task Run()
{
    UserCredential credential;

    ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets();
    secrets.ClientId = "465415811596-mqm04akgc7vhgil05hog8blvm2ns6he1.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        secrets, 
        new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets}, 
        "user", CancellationToken.None
        );

    Console.WriteLine("Accessing Google Web Systems");

    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        //HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "budget_application"
    });
}
```

I believe I have correctly set up the api through the console, as when I run this code through my computer instead of my android debug, it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem, were you able to figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to use the authorization flow that is intended for use on desktop machines. On Android, authenticating with Google should be done using the Google credentials provisioned on the device (which has a native authentication flow), not through a browser-based flow.

See also:

- [Accessing Google APIs on Android](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client)
- [Google Sign-In Quickstart for Android](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin)

Comment: Ok, so I've gotten the google drive api working with the method described in those articles, but I am hoping to use the Google sheets v4 api, and I don't understand how the two ways for authentication cross over. Once I authenticate the drive scopes, can I begin accessing the files as I would using the sheets api V4?

Comment: If you look at the reference docs for the API (such as https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create), it lists the scopes required. So, for example, it looks like "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" is sufficient. So, yes, you can reuse the GoogleAccountCredential object created for Drive to also access Sheets. (Note, though, that you need this object returned from the sign-in flow in order to issue appropriately credentialed requests).

Comment: I've read through much of the android api documentation, and I don't understand how the Google credential classes pass the data through the request interfaces. Once I instantiate the GoogleApiClient, with the drive api and the correct scopes, how would I then request the credential return?

Comment: The short answer is that you use GoogleAccountCredential.getToken() to get an access token that can be passed in the "Authorization" header (setHeader("Authorization", Bearer " + token)). You may find this documentation helpful to better understand what is going on conceptually: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: Ok, so I understand requesting authorization codes to exchange for tokens, which are used to activate the api. What I don't understand is how this is actually done. My limited  understanding of this realm of coding makes most of the syntax fly over my head.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying though, I can request the token using GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(), and then use that token, along with the scopes builder, to create and return a userCredential object, which can be used in the code I have above?